# GnuPG: Add passphrase to passphrase-less key

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp, openpgp, passphrase

I've created my PGP keypair using an online site.
The thing is, I didn't provide a passphrase upon creation; The site didn't make supplying a passphrase mandatory.

Since this key is passphraseless, GnuPG asks for it everytime I want to encrypt something, or even when using it to sign commits.
I don't have a passphrase, so when I provide an empty passphrase using `pinentry`, the program exits with error status after three attempts.

I've tried changing the passphrase via `--edit-key`, but this is impossible since it requests the passphrase.
I also can't revoke it (I've uploaded the public key to the SKS Keyservers and Biglumber), it also asks for the passphrase.

I used `--batch` mode to import it into GnuPG without it asking for a passphrase, and it succeeded.

How could I go about adding a passhprase to this private key? I searched here on SuperUser (And Google), and all the solutions I found are not working, since they rely on a passphrase.

Decrypting content works on the site I originally created the keypair at (https://sela.io/pgp/).
I know I shouldn't have used a website for key generation, but my PGP knowledge was practically non-existent.

**Note:** I can encrypt/decrypt text using my private key via other tools other than GnuPG (without a passphrase); Like the "PGP Anywhere" Chrome browser extension.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using GnuPG 2.1.x/2.2.x?

Comment: @grawity Yes, I'm using GnuPG 2.2.3.

Comment: If it's asking you for a passphrase, and it fails when you enter a wrong one, it sounds like it already has a passphrase but you just don't know it. Are you sure you can sign & decrypt things with it's secret key, not just on the site that created it? Tried finding out the passphrase from the site? Probably want to make a new one anyway, unless you explicitly trust that site now & in the future as long as the key's used

Comment: @Xen2050 I've installed a browser extension called "PGP Anywhere". I'm able to encrypt and decrypt text with it without a passphrase.
I tried to search for the other site's default passphrase, but the variable is equal to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to revoke my key using an Android application called [OpenKeychain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sufficientlysecure.keychain).

This application is able to recognize passphrase-less keypairs and therefore able to revoke such keys.

This question might have gotten no attention, but I'm sure there are more people in a similar situation that might find this answer useful.

I can now upload this key to my computer and to the SKS keyservers, effectively deterring anyone from using it.
But, a useful piece of advice: **Create a revocation certificate for your key right after creating it, and store it in a safe place. Never ignore passphrase prompts; always use one.**

This will save you from a big headache.

Answer (score 0):

> I've created my PGP keypair using an online site.

That's the worst possible thing you could ever do. Now you're not the only one that has the private key.

Always create a keypair yourself using `gpg --gen-key`.